# frustrating codeigniter setup to run a simple program

Tags: php, codeigniter

My route.php file

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pxml";
$route['pxml/(:any)']="xml/pxml";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

my index.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Reading/Writing XML</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Welcome to reading/writing XML!
        <a href="loadXML">Display</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

my class Pxml.php file

```
class PXml extends CI_Controller
{
    private $pFunc;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->pFunc=new PFunc();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        if(!file_exists('application/views/xml/index.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }
        $this->load->view('xml/index');
    }
    public function loadXML()
    {
        if(!file_exists('application/views/xml/books.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }
        else
        {
            if(!file_exists('application/controllers/books.xml'))
            {
                show_404();
            }
            $data['xml_data']=$this->pFunc->ReadXML('books.xml');
            if($data['xml_data']!=null)
            {
                $this->load->view('xml/books',$data);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Fail to load XML file";
            }
        }
    }
}


?>
```

My books.php

```
<?php    
    echo <<<EOF
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Publisher</th>
            <th>Price at Amazon.com</th>
            <th>ISBN</th>
        </tr>
    EOF;
    foreach($xml_data as $book)
    {
        echo <<<EOF
        <tr>
            <td>{$book->title}</td>
            <td>{$book->author}</td>
            <td>{$book->publisher}</td>
            <td>{$book->amazon_price}</td>
            <td>{$book['isbn']}</td>
        </tr>
        EOF;
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

I could reach the index but when I press display link I have got 404 error.

Also, I created a subfolder named xml in controlers to store pxml file. and a subfolder named xml in views to store all view file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you 100% sure that the files exist? Have you tried putting some echoes at different places in your code to see where it fails?

Comment: Have you tried taking out all of your conditionals for file_exists in the loadXML controller and just outputting a string to see if the method is being called?

Comment: Try `http://example.com/index.php/pxml/loadXML` in your browser.

Comment: Is this the same as your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536248/display-content-of-a-xml-file

Answer (score 0):

CI requires all file names to be lowercase.

Change

```
Pxml.php
```

to

```
pxml.php
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing the link to display to something like this.

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('pxml/loadxml')?>">Display</a>
```

Also did you verify if CI is throwing 404 since it could not find the view OR it cannot find the controller itself?